# why do I get "index is not defined" error using easy:search

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-easy-search

I'm just trying to set up a basic search tool in Meteor to find articles in my MongoDB collection, but I'm struggling to get off the ground (if anyone has a good tutorial for an alternative search tool I'm open to suggestions).

I've settled on [easy:search](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/) because it seemed like a simple search tool to get running, however one paragraph into their [getting started instructions](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/getting-started/) and I'm already getting an error:

> ReferenceError: Index is not defined

although correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that what the

```
import { Index, MinimongoEngine } from 'meteor/easy:search'
```

line is for?

EDIT: I have tried using the import line on both the client and the server side and I get the same error either way

Comment: To eliminate other factors, make sure that it is listed via `meteor list`, and specify which version is installed.

Comment: it's listed as version 2.0.9 and with an update (not sure why, I only just added it?) I'm in the process of updating and will check back with the results shortly

Comment: It seems that the dev added the exports after that version. The update should fix it.

Comment: great now I just have to figure out how to update it... 

it says "the specified packages are at their latest compatable versions" and when I look at the version log it looks like 2.0.9 is the most current version? https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

What am I missing in this picture? It does simultaneously have an asterix next to the version number that says there's a more new version to update to... very conflicting information!

Comment: You may have conflicting versions of an indirect dependency. Try commenting out some of the other packages in the `.meteor/packages` file and then try to update. Then uncomment them gradually.

Comment: I tried taking some of them out and got an error, now that I've put them back in (as they were before) I'm getting the same error:

C:\Users\joshm\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128187/discussion-between-masteram-and-josh-mcgee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was fixed when I included the "import" line in the "lib" folder along with the other code [(specified here)](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/) to be run on both server and client

disclaimer: I uninstalled and reinstalled meteor and may have changed something else along the way which may have been the true solution, but this appears to be the triggering change

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the package on meteor?

```
 meteor add matteodem:easy-search
```

I see that in the getting start instructions they didn't put the instruction.

See ya

Comment: yes the easy:search package is added, I added it manually via the 'packages' file

Comment: did you put these specific package?

Comment: meteor add matteodem:easy-search

Comment: on the home page I linked to above it says "meteor add easy:search", I think the matteodem version is an old version

Comment: Try with this one and give me an feedback.